# Cannot init a class method in objective c

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, objective-c, xcode

I want to create a javascript equivalent object in Objective C

consider this as a **javascript object**

```
const a = {
  name: 'Varun', //TYPE: String
  token: 'xcxjsjs' //TYPE: String, 
  base: 'someurl' //TYPE: String 
}

const b = {
  id: 'shhs' //TYPE: String 
  config: a
}
```

I tried to create equivalence of the same in Objective C by doing something like this

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface A : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy, nonnull) NSString*name;
@property (nonatomic, copy, nonnull) NSString*token;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString*base;
@end
```

Where I am setting properties like this (in .m file)

```
@implementation A

- (instancetype) init
{
  if (self = [super init]) {
    base = @"https://api.in"; //SETTING IT AS A DEFAULT VALUE
  }
  return self;
}
@end
```

And Interface B as

```
@interface B : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, nonnull) A *config;
@property (nonatomic, nullable) NSString *id;
@end
```

with its implementation being just a default code

```
@implementation B

@end
```

Now, if I would want to create and pass this as an object in say `viewDidLoad`, How would I do that?

```
- (void) setProperties:(B*_Nonnull)config;
```

### What Did I do?

In `ViewDidLoad` of my view controller

I did something like this

```
B *props = [B init];
props.id = @"Something"
props.config.name = @"Varun"; 
[view setProperties:props];
```

This is throwing error

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: B<0x104c2c930> init]: cannot
> init a class object.'

Comment: `B *props = [B init];`=> `B *props = [[B alloc] init];`.

Comment: @Larme it says `unrecognized selector sent to instance` after doing that. Could it be because I am not initializing A?

Comment: Full error message. You aren't giving the important part error of that message. But indeed `props.config.name = @"Varun";` won't work, since `props.config` is `nil` here.

Comment: `-[B copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000d16f60`

Comment: In `B`, `id` and `props` should be set to `strong` (for A) and/or `copy` (for `id`). But your error is when `[view setProperties:props];` is called, no? What `view` here?